# SendKeys is reordering the charsequence

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I recently faced an issue with `element.sendkeys()`.
It's shuffling the order of the input characters.

**Example (in Java):**

*Input:* `element.sendkeys("1234567890")`

*Text field output:* '4567890123' (or some random combination)

Can anyone help with this issue please?

Comment: Please post your code and either HTML or a real URL so we can recreate. Also, browser? WebDriver version?

Comment: I use selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0  and Chrome version 49.0.2623.110 m (64-bit).
Sorry I can't share my code, HTML or URL as I am not allowed to.

Comment: OK, but if we can't recreate, then this will likely be guesswork. What have you tried yourself, so far? E.g. have you narrowed it down to Chrome only, to a particular page, with particular selectors?

Comment: If you've had some resolution on this please update. My best guess is the element is getting the focus, or the cursor position is set sometime after the sendkeys starts, but before it finishes. I've seen this happen, but it's very hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it should not happen at first place (if you are using with Selenium latest version) http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Otherwise try

```
WebElement MyElement = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
MyElement.sendKeys("1234567890");
```

Comment: yes its similar but please note in appium when i was using sendkeys like driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendkeys(); then it used to reshuffle the text inside the sendkeys but when i used like MyElement.sendKeys("1234567890"); then it worked and stopped reshuffiling so sendkeys worked more efficient way when we called it not directly on WebElement but on a reference to a WebElement

Comment: also i noted from your comment that you are not using latest version of selenium server plz update that also if not plz update selenium to latest as well it will surely resolve your problem

Answer (score -1):

This issue is because of compatibility .
Please take latest version of browser and selenium.
Check this following link , if this help
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3516

Comment: That Issue refers to Firefox (native events), Android, and Cyrillic characters - none of which are mentioned here. If you have an authoritative reference, please update your answer.